# The default sound format for bluetooth audio quality is disabled

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I use the JBL e45bt headphones connected via Bluetooth on my Microsoft Surface Pro 4 device.

This used to work fine until just a few months ago when I got my device replaced by Microsoft.

Now, this option to allow high sound quality is disabled for all Bluetooth devices but it works normally for the built-in speakers and head-phones jack.

I tried to reinstall all drivers but with no luck. I'm desperate.. any info will be highly appreciated.
10x

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Untick Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device.

Run audio troubleshooter.

As you mentioned, issue only appears on your Bluetooth devices, go to manufacturer website to use previous Bluetooth driver for the test.

Comment: hmm, when running the trouble shooter it brings me to the sound settings window where the sound enhancements are, I guess I need to disable those but they are already disabled. beside this it didn't help..